# Importing userDefaults as [Int], then iterate with forloop and switch?

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, switch-statement, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to allow a user to pick the way their date is formatted for a custom keyboard.  So, in one view, I have:

```
var userCustomDateArrayForSaving = []
var defaultsUser = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.prefsettings.myapp")
```

and a bunch of buttons with tags as follows: [buttons with tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL3Hm.png)

When the buttons are hit, their tag is appended to the `userCustomDateArrayForSaving` variable, and when the user presses "save":

```
defaultsUser?.setValue(userCustomDateArrayForSaving, forKey: "dateSettings")
defaultsUser?.synchronize()
```

So, in the end, that might equal `[0, 53,52,10,52,22]`

---

Then, in the other view, I need do:

```
var dateStampDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.prefsettings.myapp")!.array(forKey: "dateSettings") as? [Int] ?? [Int]()
```

and when the date button is hit, I've been trying to have a for loop iterate over that array and "decode" it, like this:

```
@objc func myStampsDatePressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    //
    let date = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let proxy = textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy
    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    var localTranslatedDateString = "   "

    for dateMacro in dateStampDefaults {

        switch dateMacro {
        case 0:
            return localTranslatedDateString.append(contentsOf: (formatter.weekdaySymbols[calendar.component(.weekday, from: date)]))
        case 1:
            return localTranslatedDateString.append(contentsOf: (formatter.shortWeekdaySymbols[calendar.component(.weekday, from: date)]))
        case 2:
            return localTranslatedDateString.append(contentsOf: (formatter.veryShortWeekdaySymbols[calendar.component(.weekday, from: date)]))
        case 10:
            return localTranslatedDateString.append(contentsOf: (formatter.monthSymbols[calendar.component(.month, from: date)]))
        case 11:
            return localTranslatedDateString.append(contentsOf: (formatter.shortMonthSymbols[calendar.component(.month, from: date)]))
        case 12:
            return localTranslatedDateString.append(contentsOf: (formatter.veryShortMonthSymbols[calendar.component(.month, from: date)]))
    ...(etc)    
    }

    let str = formatter.string(from: Date())
    myStampLengthForDelete = str
    proxy.insertText(localTranslatedDateString)

}
```

...so that someone could have their date show up as "Monday, December 1st", for example.

Can anyone lend some advice?  Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Are the `return`s in the `switch` intentional?

Comment: no, the returns were the problem.  brainfart.  thanks all

Answer (score 0):

So yea.... you have a simple misspelling.

```
defaultsUser?.setValue(userCustomDateArrayForSaving, forKey: "dateSettings")
defaultsUser?.synchronize()

var dateStampDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.prefsettings.myapp")!.array(forKey: "dateSetting") as? [Int] ?? [Int]()
```

should be

```
var dateStampDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.prefsettings.myapp")!.array(forKey: "dateSettings") as? [Int] ?? [Int]() //THE last s IN dateSetting(s)
```

**Note:**

Tested below and it prints `[0, 53, 52, 10, 52, 2]`.

```
var userCustomDateArrayForSaving = [0, 53,52,10,52,2]
var defaultsUser = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.prefsettings.myapp")

defaultsUser?.setValue(userCustomDateArrayForSaving, forKey: "dateSettings")
defaultsUser?.synchronize()

var dateStampDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.prefsettings.myapp")!.array(forKey: "dateSettings") as? [Int] ?? [Int]()

print(dateStampDefaults)
```

Comment: and this is why you should extract out such constants into variables.

Comment: Apologies, I actually caught that misspelling in my code before I posted, but didn't fix it here.  Does anything else look wrong?  Is this a silly way to try to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: thank you very much for your help.  If you get a moment, could you please take a look at how I've constructed the function?  It's not working.  In any case, thanks again!

Comment: It must be where you are calling ‘setValue’ but we don’t see that. We only see that you are calling it. Show more code, I suppose